# What is the recommended way to deal with git commits of files inside /wwwroot in ASP .NET Core projects?

Tags: git, asp.net-core, static-libraries, wwwroot

I have multiple static files and libraries in my /wwwroot folder that are obviously required to run my App. However, I also have JS libraries for additional content in there that I sourced from somewhere else.

If I understand correctly, you are not supposed to commit code that is not yours. But how can I make sure that other people can run my code properly if I should not include my downloaded JS libraries then? I have just started working with JS and expanding my static content. It may be an easy point but I probably missed it.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly fine to commit libraries, code snippets, etc you downloaded or got somewhere on the internet.

Git won't complain. Your team mates won't complain. None will.

Software development is all about building libraries, sharing them for future use, to shorten future development time and provide better code.